# Topology definition, finite intersection, infinite union?

Tags: general-topology, definition

In my textbook I find:

> **Definition of a topology**
>
> $\tau$ as a collection of subsets of $X$ is a topology on $X$ if:
>
> 1. $\varnothing, X \in \tau$
> 2. If $\mathscr{F}\subseteq \tau$ then $\bigcup_{U\in \mathscr{F}} U \in \tau$
> 3. $U,V\in \tau$ then $U\cap V\in \tau$

While working through topology, I started to get confused with the concept of a topology. Two rather basic (even trivial?) questions arose?

#### First question

On wikipedia I read:

3. Any intersection of finitely many elements of $\tau$ is an element of $\tau$

But isn't that a different definition from the one in my textbook? 
The definition my textbook keeps the possibility of a infinite, but countable intersection? Which one is valid?

#### Second question

Why couldn't 2. be written as $U, V\in \tau$ then $U\cup V \in \tau$.

I guess it has to do with the countability of sets, but could some give an example of an uncountable union of sets? Would this mean something like $\tau_\text{discrete}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. If the intersection of any two open sets is open, then a straightforward induction tells you that the intersection of any finite number of open sets is open. (And if any intersection of a finite number of open sets is open then taking $n = 2$ we get that the intersection of any two open sets is open). This shows that they are equivalent. Neither of these tells you anything about infinite intersections of open sets. (You say "The definition my textbook keeps the possibility of a infinite, but countable intersection", but it doesn't do any such thing - why did you think it did? The only thing it tells you is that the intersection of any two open sets is open.)

For an example, consider $U_n = (-1/n, 1/n) \subset \mathbb{R}$. This is a countable family of open sets whose intersection is $\{0\}$, which is not open.

Q2. Again, the union of any two open sets being open tells you nothing about infinite unions of open sets, including countable unions.

Comment: The confusion cleared out, I was thinking of an something like. $U_i \in \tau$, then $\bigcap_{i=1}^N U_i$ in $\tau$, then $\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^N U_i \right) \cap U_{N+1} \in \tau$ and then I thought I could continue this induction wise into infinity. But I see now that by using this concept I always get a finite intersection, and never reach the infinite intersection.

Answer (score 1):

If $U,V\in \tau$ does not it follow that finite intersection of elements of $\tau$ is in $\tau $??(Why)

Take $(U_1\cap U_2....\cap U_n)=(U_1\cap U_2....\cap U_{n-1})\cap U_n$

As far your second question if union of any two members is in $\tau$ it does not follow that arbitrary union is in $\tau$